# ensuring transducer (transmitter) and receiver polarity

Tags: transmitter, receiver, ultrasound, polarity, transducer

I am trying to implement a simple phased array of 7 transmitters rated 40 kHz. I have a few receivers to measure the acoustic field generated to validate if it works. What is a simple way to measure the polarity as I am skeptical to just use the marked polarity.

Thanks!

Comment: A link to the data sheet might help.

Comment: what error analysis have you done, regarding effect of different resonant frequencies in your seven TX circuits?

Answer (score 0):

One approach that I used when I was a sonar engineer is to energize the transmitters one at a time.  Measure the output which should increase every time a new transmitter is added. If the level decreases, then the transmitter is probably wired backwards.